# VS 2017 - Very slow to start and end debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

After an OS upgrade every debugging session that I start in Visual Studio 2017 takes about 90 sec to start and about 45 sec to terminate.  During that time one CPU core is running at 100%.

I've tried the various fixes like turning off debug options in Resharper etc but that did not help.

Comment: Hi Peter, Since you have shared your solution for this issue, please consider to marking your answer so that it will help other community members handle similar issues. Just as a reminder:)

Comment: @Peter Hinz, Glad to know that this issue has been resolve, in addition, whether your app was created by old version or the VS2017 itself? Whether it will has this issue again if you debug it in the next time? Open Visual Studio | Tools | Options | Text Editor | C/C++ | Advanced |Under "Intellisense" category set "Disable Automatic Precompiled Header" to true. Check it again

Answer (score 2):

The one fix that has worked consistently is to delete the .vs folder from your project folder.
Steps:

1) exit all instances of Visual Studio

2) open the folder that contains the project solution file (.sln)

3) Delete the `.vs` folder

4) Relaunch visual studio and rebuild your app. You should be back to full speed debugging

Comment: This method also works for Visual Studio 2019